# Add column sorting feature on treegrid html

Tags: javascript, jquery, treegrid, columnsorting

I have a treegrid that is build like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="treegrid-0">
            <th>name2</th>
            <th>type2</th>
            <th>Number2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-1">
            <th>name1</th>
            <th>type1</th>
            <th>Number1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1" style="display:none;">
            <th>name1-A</th>
            <th>type1-A</th>
            <th>Number1-A</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1" style="display:none;">
            <th>name1-B</th>
            <th>type1-B</th>
            <th>Number1-B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="treegrid-4">
            <th>name0</th>
            <th>type0</th>
            <th>Number0</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to add the sorting option when i click on a column.
The sorting option has to be done only on the top parent.
It's a treegrid, so the expected behaviour is that the child nodes has to be moved also with the parent if the parent has to move.

How can i do that with JS ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing all the hard work yourself, you can use the awesome js/jQuery library: datatables: https://datatables.net/

Just after defining your table, give it an ID

```
<table id = "myTable">..</table>
```

and then add the following snippet which will transform your table into an awesome table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i already know Datatable, but for my project, it's mandatory to use a treetable view that display data with a hierarchical view..